# Why libstdc++'s std::vector's ctor implementation doesn't cause memory leaks?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, memory-leaks

I'm using GCC 7.3.0 with libstdc++.

Here is `std::vector`'s ctor implementation.

```
      vector(initializer_list<value_type> __l,
         const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
      : _Base(__a)
      {
    _M_range_initialize(__l.begin(), __l.end(),
                random_access_iterator_tag());
      }

      // Called by the second initialize_dispatch above
      template<typename _ForwardIterator>
    void
    _M_range_initialize(_ForwardIterator __first,
                _ForwardIterator __last, std::forward_iterator_tag)
    {
      const size_type __n = std::distance(__first, __last);
      this->_M_impl._M_start = this->_M_allocate(__n);
      this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = this->_M_impl._M_start + __n;
      this->_M_impl._M_finish =
        std::__uninitialized_copy_a(__first, __last,
                    this->_M_impl._M_start,
                    _M_get_Tp_allocator());
    }
```

In function `_M_range_initialize(_ForwardIterator,_ForwardIterator,std::forward_iterator_tag)`, when `std::__uninitialized_copy_a` throws an exception, `this->_M_impl._M_start`, that was allocated in this function, will not be released, I think.

That means this implementation will cause a memory leak.

However, libstdc++ is well-tested, well-known library. My understanding must be incorrect.

Why is there no memory leak in this implementation?

Comment: "_when `std::__uninitialized_copy_a` throw exception_" How do you know that it may throw an exception? Such information is not present in a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the rare case that `__uinitialized_copy_a` throws (only when the allocator used does), the memory will get deallocated by the destructor of `_Vector_base` just as always.

It's basically the same thing as if you threw an exception in your own code with a local `std::vector` in scope, or if a local static allocated `std::vector` goes out of scope. The memory gets deallocated by the vector in the destructor.

In this function, notice that `_uinitialized_copy_a` only *copies* the elements over. The storage is already there and valid. You would be correct if the storage wasn't assigned to the vector's internal storage variable, but this is not the case here and the storage can be deallocated as always.

Comment: >deallocated by the destructor of _Vector_base

Oh...I missed it!